# How can I find the current filename from a file object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How do I find the current filename, if all I have is the file object?

The file is one that a user uploads, and I want to find its name but, if I use `file_object.path`, it gives the name that the file was created as, rather than the current name.

That produced a name that seemed like a random bunch of numbers and letters; The sample file was a certificate I created which is the type of file the user will upload, so I want to make sure I show the current file name so it's not confusing.

Comment: What does it have to do with `jQuery`???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is "you can't".

To understand why, in a typical filesystem a file is just a node (or in Unix/Linux-speak, an inode) which can be referred to by many links, and I'm not talking about symlinks.

For example:

```
$ echo "i am foo" > foo
$ cat foo
i am foo
$ ln foo bar    # this is a hard link, not a symlink
$ rm foo
$ cat bar
i am foo
$ rm bar
$ cat bar
cat: bar: No such file or directory
$ cat foo
cat: foo: No such file or directory
```

In fact, if you look at the Ruby documentation for File::Stat...

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/File/Stat.html

...you'll see that there is a method `nlink` that returns the number of hard links to the file.
You'll also see that there is a method `inspect` which returns attributes for the file, but no names.

Comment: Do you know how others are able to display the file name when I upload a document? For example, I changed the name of a file and uploaded it as an attachment in gmail and the new name was shown? How can something like that be done?

Comment: Look at the documentation here  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#uploading-files

Comment: The point is that when the file is uploaded, your app is saving it and you have complete control over that. Perhaps you're using a gem to assist in the process, but I answered your original question. Good luck with it.